# Is there a way to bulk edit relationship permissions?

Tags: permissions, relationships

I have about 70 organizations that we imported with individuals - that will have permissions to view and update information.  Is there a way to make sure they can have that permission when we import or bulk edit that information.  Right now I am adding permissions one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API, or the [API CSV import GUI](https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui).  Either way you'll need to have some way of identifying the relationships that need editing.

While I don't recommend running SQL directly against the database, this is one instance where it will be safe - IF you aren't using inherited ("conferred") relationships.